# What are the prior arts related to the patent in question?

Tags: prior-art-request, wo2000034241a1

How is the patent in question more better and novel as compared to the prior arts?

In reference to the patent: [WO2000034241A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2000034241A1)

Comment: It sounds like you may have something in mind? Is there a specific piece of prior art that you'd like contrasted against this application? Note that whatever you find will likely have to be from before around 1998.

Answer (score 1):

I think below articles are good prior-arts

[Pyrrolidides: synthesis and structure-activity relationship as inhibitors of dipeptidyl peptidase IV](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0223523497890824)

[2-cyanopyrrolidides as potent, stable inhibitors of dipeptidyl peptidase IV](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0960894X96001904)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar German patent which has been filed on 2 May 1991 and granted on 29 April 1993: DE 41 14 268 C2.

Another German patent was filed on 6 July 1994 and granted on 1 September 1995: DE4423822 C1.

There was also a presentation at a conference:
W.K. Schomburg, M. Vitt, W. Bacher, M.W. Börner, W. Menz
"Measurements of  Physical Parameters with Ultrasound and Microdiaphragms"
Oral presentation and Proceedings of Micro Electro Mechanical Systems '95, 29 Jan. -2 Feb. 1995 in Amsterdam (1995) 139 - 144.

Even earlier there was a presentation at another conference and published in a journal:
M.W. Börner, S. zur Horst-Meyer, M.C. Murphy, H.-J. Münch, W.K. Schomburg, M. Vitt, "Ultrasonic Measurements With Micromembranes", EUROSENSORS VIII in Toulouse (1994) and Sensors and Actuators A 46 - 47 (1995) 62 - 65.